# How does the linker deal with definitions in headers in C++?

Tags: c++, linker, toolchain

I would like to understand better how the linker works when building c++ code.

If I define a function or a global variable in multiple cpp files, I get linker errors for multiple definitions. That makes sense, because I have multiple versions and the linker cannot decide on a particular one. To circumvent that, one only writes/includes the declaration, (signature only for functions, extern for variables).
However, I have noticed that you CAN define methods in class declarations, and at least most here deem that acceptable or even good practice for trivial functions (like trivial getters and setters), because it allows the compiler to inline these functions (and also, it is necessary for templates).

In the discussion around "pragma once", I got that in some situations, the toolchain will not be able to distinguish if a file is the same or not, so in principle, it could happen that two cpp files get the same class name declared from different headers, but with different definitions of such header-only methods, couldn't it?

I have tried to set up an example:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class1.hpp"
#include "Class2.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Class1 c1;
  Class2 c2(c1);

  c1.set(1);
  cout << c1.get() << endl;
  c2.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Class1.hpp:

```
#ifndef CLASS1_HPP
#define CLASS1_HPP
#warning Class1

class Class1 {
  public:
  void set(int i) { val = i; };
  int get() {return val;};

  int val=0;
};

#endif
```

Class1a.hpp

```
#ifndef CLASS1_HPP
#define CLASS1_HPP
#warning Class1a

class Class1 {
  public:
  void set(int i) { val = i; };
  int get() {return -1*val;};

  int val=0;
};

#endif
```

Class2.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CLASS2_HPP
#define CLASS2_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "Class1a.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Class2 {
  public:
  Class2(Class1 &c1) : c1(c1) {};
  void print();

  Class1& c1;
};

#endif
```

Class2.cpp

```
#include "Class2.hpp"

void Class2::print() {
  cout << c1.get() << endl;
}
```

However, I get the following output:

```
$ g++ *.cpp; ./a.out     
In file included from Class2.hpp:6:0,
                 from Class2.cpp:1:
Class1a.hpp:4:2: warning: #warning Class1a [-Wcpp]
 #warning Class1a
  ^~~~~~~
-1
-1
```

I don't quite get why Class1(not-a) is never seen by the precompiler despite the fact that it is included first in main.cpp, so I guess my question extends to that ... [Edit: I cannot reproduce the precompiler issue anymore, this now produces the same result as the code below, as I expected originally]

Edit: removed pragma once to avoid forther confusion and deviations.

---

Ok, since people seem to get this mixed up, here is what I would have expected the result of the precompiler to be:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class1 {
  public:
  void set(int i) { val = i; };
  int get() {return val;}; // <-- This line is different!

  int val=0;
};

class Class2 {
  public:
  Class2(Class1 &c1) : c1(c1) {};
  void print();

  Class1& c1;
};

int main() {
  Class1 c1;
  Class2 c2(c1);

  c1.set(1);
  cout << c1.get() << endl;
  c2.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Class2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class1 {
  public:
  void set(int i) { val = i; };
  int get() {return -1*val;};

  int val=0;
};


class Class2 {
  public:
  Class2(Class1 &c1) : c1(c1) {};
  void print();

  Class1& c1;
};

void Class2::print() {
  cout << c1.get() << endl;
}
```

No idea why the precompiler thing before did not work. Maybe someone cares to explain, despite the fact that it is not my main question. And, yes, of course I know that writing such code is a bad idea, I just want to know how it is dealt with. Completely academic question.

What I find now is that the output of the executable depends on the order in which I state the cpp files for g++:

```
$ g++ main.cpp Class2.cpp
$ ./a.out                
1
1
$ g++ Class2.cpp main.cpp 
$ ./a.out                 
-1
-1
```

So at some point, the linker seems to grab the next best version of the method. Why does the same not seem to happen with functions and variables, and could it be avoided (because this seems like something that should at least produce a warning)?

---

Additional example with functions.
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int get() {return 1;} 
void print();

int main() {
  cout << get() << endl;
  print();
}
```

method2.cpp

```
int get() { return -1; }

void print() {
  cout << get() << endl;
}
```

Here, the multiple definition gets caught:

```
$ g++ main.cpp method2.cpp 
/tmp/ccjCKBLm.o: In function `get()':
method2.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `get()'
/tmp/ccnvH0iR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccnvH0iR.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I add inline to the functions, then it compiles again, but always returns 1 despite the order of the arguments of g++, which is in line (no pun intended) with the winning answer below.

Comment: This is covered by the **one definition rule**.

Comment: Note: "linker works when compiling c++". The linker doesn't compile anything. It just links compiled modules. The whole process is called "building"

Comment: @Max Can you explain? In wikipedia, the only helpful sentence there seems to be "For a given entity, each definition must have the same sequence of tokens." Does that mean if my header-defined methods show up at different places, it is fine as long as they are the same letter by letter? It also says that objects in different computational units are different entities, shouldn't that mean that the two outputs in my example should be different?

Comment: @P. Dmitry Thanks, changed.

Comment: Recommended reads: [Linkers and loaders](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) and wikipage on [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))s and [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and [documentation of `g++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/)

Comment: Read also the [specification of C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I would guess that is the answer to literally any C++ question here.

Comment: Typo, sorry. Class1(a) is header only. There should not be a Class1.cpp. It is fixed now.
Thanks for taking the time to explain and source this instead of just quoting the ODR. The key info was that this happens with INLINE functions and methods in class definitions are implicitly inline.

Comment: FWIW, I can't tell you why `#warning Class1` is not output - it should be as soon as `main.cpp` is compiled. But this is more or less orthogonal to the whole ODR-stuff (I understand why it's part of the question though). Can you reproduce this without any of the class definitions present, just empty (except for includes/macros/pragmas) files?

Comment: Yes, it is a completely different question, but I wanted an example and I got the idea to late to just hardcode the defintition twice. actually, now I cannot even reproduce it WITH the class stuff anymore. Wierd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`[basic.def.odr]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10.sentence-1), we have:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required. [...]

This makes having multiple definitions of a (non-inline) function or variable an ODR violation. The linker is not *required* to diagnose this, but since it is usually easy to do so, you will frequently see this diagnosed.

Then we have [`[basic.def.odr]/12`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12):

> There can be more than one definition of a
>
> [...]
>
> - inline function [...]
>
> [...]
>
> in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. [...] Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens, [...]
>
> [...]
>
> [...] If the definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, then the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Your `Class1::get` method violates this. It is implicitly `inline` (because it is defined in a class definition, see [`[dcl.inline]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#4) - the above rules are also summarized in that section), so having multiple definitions is allowed, but they do not consist of the same token sequence.

Once again, no diagnostic is required. Checking the consistency of multiple definitions of inline functions (and all the other things that I skipped in the above quotes) is not feasible for the linker, so it generally makes no attempt to do so.

---

> in principle, it could happen that two cpp files get the same class name declared from different headers, but with different definitions of such header-only methods, couldn't it?

That could happen, yes, and it would be an ODR violation, making the program ill-formed, no diagnostic required. The use of include guard macros is a solid countermeasure.

Note that this isn't limited to different headers declaring the same class, but also e.g. the same header being included with different `#define` situations so that the preprocessed definitions differ between inclusions of the same header file.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. I have also added examples with (optionally inline) functions which confirm this. I upvoted both yours and eerorika's answer but selected yours as an answer for the better source situation.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the linker deal with definitions in headers in C++?

If there are multiple inline definitions across translation units, then the linker picks one, any of the definitions and discards the rest. Only one is needed, since all definitions must be identical.

> [pragma once] it could happen that two cpp files get the same class name declared from different headers, but with different definitions of such header-only methods, couldn't it?

That can't happen as consequence of misidentified pragma once. The content of the header is still the same and thus the definition of the functions are the same. The problem with this case is that there will be multiple definitions of types, non-inline functions or variables within single translation unit, which also violates the one definition rule. Luckily, this type of violation is trivial for the compiler to diagnose.

> I don't quite get why Class1(not-a) is never seen by the precompiler

It is seen by the pre-compiler. You can see it from the output:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
./Class1.hpp:3:2: warning: Class1 [-W#warnings]
#warning Class1
 ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from Class2.cpp:1:
In file included from ./Class2.hpp:6:
./Class1a.hpp:3:2: warning: Class1a [-W#warnings]
#warning Class1a
```

> No idea why that did not work.

It didn't work, because you violated the ODR. Therefore your program is ill-formed. The implementation (i.e. tool chain i.e. compiler, linker etc.) is not required to diagnose this particular issue. If the linker was required to diagnose the issue, it would have to check every inline definition in every translation unit to make sure that they are identical. This could become quite expensive for large compilations.

> Why does the same not seem to happen with functions and variables

Same happens to all inline functions and inline variables (inline variables are a new thing in C++17), not just inline member functions. It's not a problem to non-inline functions or non-inline variables, since ODR rule allows only one definition across all translation units, so the linker can easily tell that you messed up when it finds more than one.

> could it be avoided (because this seems like something that should at least produce a warning)?

I haven't seen any linker that would diagnose this violation. Best advice I have is to have good naming discipline (use namespaces to avoid name collisions), and testing discipline (so that you detect wrong behaviour in case there is a collision).

Comment: "It is seen by the pre-compiler."  Maybe I frased that badly. The precompiler does not seem to go into the header guard, as the warning is not printed. That is despite the fact that Class1 is included first (and then Class1a via Class2) and the header guard should prevent the inclusion of Class1a instead of Class1. I have omitted that in the additional example by putting the declarations in the cpp files. Still not quite sure why that was necessary.

Comment: "It didn't work, because you violated the ODR" That sentence referred to the behavior of the precompiler which should not be concerned by the ODR.

Answer (score 1):

The linker doesn't deal with header files at all. The compiler (in the preprocessor phase) textually inserts the contents of headers into the source files. The resulting Translation Unit is then compiled.

`pragma once` is irrelevant in your examples; you use the equivalent-but-portable header guards. Again, this is a preprocessor thing, so header guards are also not seen by the linker either. They prevent duplicate insertion of a single header in a single translation unit.

As for the actual C++, you violate the One Definition Rule (as Max Langhof pointed out in comments). That means all bets are of; it's Undefined Behavior. There is no "understanding how the linker works" in the presence of Undefined behavior.

Comment: No, that is just a separate issue. I TRIED to set up an example in which main.cpp and class2.cpp get declarations of Class1 with different definitions of the set() method.
However, that seems to have failed for some reason related to the precompiler that I do not understand. The header guards are there to avoid compiler errors in main.cpp, the pragma once are there because I normally use to put them. I know that they are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @mcandril: I don't understand why you keep blaming the preprocessor phase of the compiler for that.  But formally it doesn't really matter. What you do is disallowed.

Comment: I have added an example now that omits the precompiler issue.

Comment: " you violate the One Definition Rule" OK. Why is the rule in my experience automatically caught for multiple definitions of variables and functions, but not for methods? Is this a principle limitation ("Can not be known at built time")? Why?

Comment: @mcandril You have two different definitions for the method `Class1::get` (because they have a different sequence of tokens). That violates the one definition rule and is plain undefined behavior. The compiler (/linker) is not required to diagnose this, as it becomes arbitrarily hard to notice/prove this in more complex cases, so it makes no attempt to do so. The compiler works per-source file and produces an object file, the linker only sees the object files and not the code. In the presence of optimizations, it's simply infeasible for the linker to prove definitions being different.

Comment: @mcandril In this specific case: Methods that are defined within the class definition are implicitly `inline`. Thus, every translation unit gets its own copy and the linker picks any one of them (and just assumes they are identical, because proving otherwise is too hard in general). For non-inline functions (and variables), the presence of duplicates _themselves_ is what's problematic.

Comment: I absolutely get that it violates the ODR and I that it is not right. I think your last post clarifies it, because it answers why it is caught with functions, but not methods.